# Removing laminate glue

Tags: adhesive, removal, wooden-furniture

I inherited a antique wood table and would like to remove the laminate that was added to it. I know how to get the laminate off, but what is the best way to remove the glue from the wood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, contact cement usually the common glue for laminates.  If it is contact cement, the glue should feel a bit rubbery.

The removers are usually acetone, lacquer thinner, or a contact cement cleaner/remover.

With this stuff, no smoking and doing it outside is good.

The table will probably need sanding and refinishing to bring it back looking good.

The woodworking site will probably have the best information for making that table look its best.